# is there a way to set default custom routes for asp.net core with angular project template

Tags: angular, asp.net-core-3.0

I am using asp.net core 3.1 with angular template and am trying to make a website 
that automatically re-routes to the root of the website appended by 5 random letters (like discord in a way)

for example, let's say my website is `localhost.com`. If I go in `localhost.com` then it would automatically re-routes me to `localhost.com/aspzk`

I feel like I can achieve this via configuring `app-routing-module.ts` but I'm pretty sure that angular is client-sided and I want to do routing via server-side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can leave your(my) attribute route blank and fill the method with RedirectToAction, make sure to leave the actionName blank

```
[Route("")]
    [ApiController]
    public class HomeController : ControllerBase
    {
        public IActionResult RedirectToRandomID()
        {
            return RedirectToAction("", "abcde");
        }
    }
```